# Error when installing erlang

Tags: erlang

After upgrading system to OSX 10.9, errors found when compiling erlang.

Env: OSX 10.9

Erlang version: R15B01

Build via `kerl build R15B01 r15b01`

```
beam/erl_bif_re.c: In function ‘erts_init_bif_re’:
beam/erl_bif_re.c:68: error: ‘erts_pcre_malloc’ undeclared (first use in this function)
beam/erl_bif_re.c:68: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
beam/erl_bif_re.c:68: error: for each function it appears in.)
beam/erl_bif_re.c:69: error: ‘erts_pcre_free’ undeclared (first use in this function)
beam/erl_bif_re.c:70: error: ‘erts_pcre_stack_malloc’ undeclared (first use in this function)
beam/erl_bif_re.c:71: error: ‘erts_pcre_stack_free’ undeclared (first use in this function)
beam/erl_bif_re.c: In function ‘build_compile_result’:
beam/erl_bif_re.c:398: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘erts_pcre_fullinfo’
beam/erl_bif_re.c:403: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘erts_pcre_free’
beam/erl_bif_re.c: In function ‘re_compile’:
beam/erl_bif_re.c:457: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘erts_pcre_compile2’
beam/erl_bif_re.c:458: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
beam/erl_bif_re.c: In function ‘cleanup_restart_context’:
beam/erl_bif_re.c:513: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘erts_pcre_free_restart_data’
beam/erl_bif_re.c: In function ‘build_capture’:
beam/erl_bif_re.c:822: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘erts_pcre_get_stringnumber’
beam/erl_bif_re.c: In function ‘re_run’:
beam/erl_bif_re.c:910: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
beam/erl_bif_re.c:988: error: ‘PCRE_EXTRA_LOOP_LIMIT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
beam/erl_bif_re.c:990: error: ‘pcre_extra’ has no member named ‘loop_limit’
beam/erl_bif_re.c:993: error: ‘pcre_extra’ has no member named ‘loop_limit’
beam/erl_bif_re.c:994: error: ‘pcre_extra’ has no member named ‘loop_limit’
beam/erl_bif_re.c:997: error: ‘pcre_extra’ has no member named ‘restart_data’
beam/erl_bif_re.c:998: error: ‘pcre_extra’ has no member named ‘restart_flags’
beam/erl_bif_re.c:999: error: ‘pcre_extra’ has no member named ‘loop_counter_return’
beam/erl_bif_re.c:1063: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘erts_pcre_exec’
beam/erl_bif_re.c:1067: error: ‘PCRE_ERROR_LOOP_LIMIT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
beam/erl_bif_re.c: In function ‘re_exec_trap’:
beam/erl_bif_re.c:1128: error: ‘pcre_extra’ has no member named ‘loop_limit’
beam/erl_bif_re.c:1131: error: ‘pcre_extra’ has no member named ‘loop_limit’
beam/erl_bif_re.c:1132: error: ‘pcre_extra’ has no member named ‘loop_limit’
beam/erl_bif_re.c:1134: error: ‘pcre_extra’ has no member named ‘loop_counter_return’
beam/erl_bif_re.c:1135: error: ‘pcre_extra’ has no member named ‘restart_data’
beam/erl_bif_re.c:1136: error: ‘pcre_extra’ has no member named ‘restart_flags’
beam/erl_bif_re.c:1144: error: ‘PCRE_ERROR_LOOP_LIMIT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make[3]: *** [obj/i386-apple-darwin13.0.0/opt/smp/erl_bif_re.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [opt] Error 2
make[1]: *** [smp] Error 2
make: *** [emulator] Error 2
```

Any advice, thank you.

Comment: A similar problem was reported [here](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2013-March/072801.html).

Comment: @legoscia Thank you for the link. I configured and make again with `export CFLAGS="" LDFLAGS=""`. Problem solved.

Comment: @goofansu: If the problem is now fixed please consider answering your own question. Future visitors will benefit from having the answer here.

Comment: @Tim Sorry, there are other errors found when compiling for a while. I'm investigating in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed pcre8.33 with homebrew which is conflicting with erlang's pcre library.

Problem solved after uninstall the pcre and make again.